# php safe mode in server

Tags: php

If this returns true, does it mean safe mode is on or off?

```
if( !ini_get('safe_mode') ){
    echo 'TRUE';
}  else {
    echo 'FALSE';
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really return anything. IT echo'es.

Comment: What is your question about: The way `!` works, what kind of values `ini_get` returns, or something else?

Comment: Do people on this site get paid money per word?  I cannot believe no one has answered this...

Comment: Yes, you will get the bill soon ;) In the meantime you could help others to help you and answer their questions in the comments.

Comment: Guy gets 103 questions answered for free, doesn't see fit to clarify a crappy question, but has the cheek to complain about the service. Hats off

Answer (score 3):

It echoes FALSE if safe mode is on, however, safe mode is [**`deprecated`**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) as of PHP 5.3

Answer (score 1):

Echoes true if `ini_get('safe_mode')` is false so this piece of code echoes the opposite of the safe mode state.

Answer (score 0):

A bit off topic, but try `var_dump(ini_get('safe_mode'))` next time...

Comment: var_dump doesn't show anything when I use firefox and have to use echo.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that it's pretty basic without xdebug installed. If you set up the xdebug extension for PHP, var_dump will give you the contents of your variable via nicely formatted HTML